# Could not deduce (IHP.RouterSupport.AutoRoute (Id' "hardwareVendors"))

Tags: haskell, ihp

It looks like I'm not passing the correct parameter to this action. I'm not sure how to debug this error though :/ Any tips on getting started?

error:

```
Web/View/HardwareVendors/Show.hs:8:33
    • Could not deduce (IHP.RouterSupport.AutoRoute
                          (Id' "hardwareVendors"))
        arising from a use of ‘IHP.HSX.QQ.applyAttribute’
      from the context: (?context::ControllerContext, ?view::ShowView)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   html :: (?context::ControllerContext, ?view::ShowView) =>
                           ShowView -> Text.Blaze.Html.Html
        at Web/View/HardwareVendors/Show.hs:8:5-8
    • In the expression:
        ((IHP.HSX.QQ.applyAttribute
            ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "id"#) 2))
           ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# " id=\""#) 5))
          ((get #id) hardwareVendor)
      In the second argument of ‘IHP.HSX.QQ.applyAttributes’, namely
        ‘[\ h_aArT
            -> (h_aArT
                  ! ((Text.Blaze.Internal.attribute
                        (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                           ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "type"#) 4)))
                       (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                          ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# " type=\""#) 7)))
                      (preEscapedTextValue ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "hidden"#) 6))),
          \ h_aArU
            -> (h_aArU
                  ! ((Text.Blaze.Internal.attribute
                        (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                           ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "name"#) 4)))
                       (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                          ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# " name=\""#) 7)))
                      (preEscapedTextValue
                         ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "hardwareVendorId"#) 16))),
          ((IHP.HSX.QQ.applyAttribute
              ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "id"#) 2))
             ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# " id=\""#) 5))
            ((get #id) hardwareVendor),
          \ h_aArV
            -> (h_aArV
                  ! ((Text.Blaze.Internal.attribute
                        (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                           ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "class"#) 5)))
                       (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                          ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# " class=\""#) 8)))
                      (preEscapedTextValue
                         ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "form-control"#) 12)))]’
      In the expression:
        (IHP.HSX.QQ.applyAttributes
           ((((Text.Blaze.Internal.Leaf
                 (IHP.HSX.QQ.textToStaticString
                    ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "input"#) 5)))
                (IHP.HSX.QQ.textToStaticString
                   ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "<input"#) 6)))
               (IHP.HSX.QQ.textToStaticString
                  ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# ">"#) 1)))
              ()))
          [\ h_aArT
             -> (h_aArT
                   ! ((Text.Blaze.Internal.attribute
                         (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                            ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "type"#) 4)))
                        (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                           ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# " type=\""#) 7)))
                       (preEscapedTextValue ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "hidden"#) 6))),
           \ h_aArU
             -> (h_aArU
                   ! ((Text.Blaze.Internal.attribute
                         (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                            ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "name"#) 4)))
                        (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                           ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# " name=\""#) 7)))
                       (preEscapedTextValue
                          ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "hardwareVendorId"#) 16))),
           ((IHP.HSX.QQ.applyAttribute
               ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "id"#) 2))
              ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# " id=\""#) 5))
             ((get #id) hardwareVendor),
           \ h_aArV
             -> (h_aArV
                   ! ((Text.Blaze.Internal.attribute
                         (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                            ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "class"#) 5)))
                        (Text.Blaze.Internal.textTag
                           ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# " class=\""#) 8)))
                       (preEscapedTextValue
                          ((Data.Text.unpackCStringLen# "form-control"#) 12)))]
  |
8 |     html ShowView { .. } = [hsx|
  |                                 ^...
 
<interactive>:47:37
    Variable not in scope: app :: Async a0
    Suggested fix:
      Perhaps use ‘ClassyPrelude.ap’ (imported from ClassyPrelude)
```

./Controller/HardwareVendor.hs

```
module Web.Controller.HardwareVendors where

import Web.Controller.Prelude
import Web.View.HardwareVendors.Index
import Web.View.HardwareVendors.Show
import Web.View.HardwareVendors.ShowResponse

instance Controller HardwareVendorsController where
    action HardwareVendorsAction = do
        hardwareVendors <- query @HardwareVendor |> fetch
        render IndexView { .. }

    action ShowHardwareVendorAction { hardwareVendorId } = do
        hardwareVendor <- fetch hardwareVendorId
        render ShowView { .. }

    action ShowHardwareVendorResponseAction { hardwareVendorId } = do
        hardwareVendor <- fetch hardwareVendorId
        render ShowResponseView { .. }
```

```
-- View/HardwareVendors/Show.hs

module Web.View.HardwareVendors.Show where
import Data.Text as Text
import Web.View.Prelude

data ShowView = ShowView { hardwareVendor :: HardwareVendor }

instance View ShowView where
    html ShowView { .. } = [hsx|
    <form id="select-vendor-form" action="/ShowHardwareVendorResponse" method="get">
      {renderInputs hardwareVendor}
      <input type="hidden" type="text" name="hardwareVendorId" value={get #id HardwareVendor} class="form-control" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

|]
renderInputs :: HardwareVendor -> Html
renderInputs vendor = [hsx|
        {forEach (requiredfields vendor) renderInput}
|]

renderInput :: Text -> Html
renderInput field = [hsx|
      <label for={field}>{field}</label>
      <input type="text" name={field} id={field} class="form-control" />
|]
```

Web/Types.hs:

```
module Web.Types where

import IHP.Prelude
import IHP.ModelSupport
import Generated.Types

data WebApplication = WebApplication deriving (Eq, Show)

data HardwareVendorsController
    = HardwareVendorsAction
    | ShowHardwareVendorAction { hardwareVendorId :: !(Id HardwareVendor) }
    | ShowHardwareVendorResponseAction { hardwareVendorId :: !(Id HardwareVendor) }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data)
```

related issue: https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/community/ShowThread?threadId=ad73d6a5-2481-4e2f-af46-9bf8849f998b

silly stackoverflow validation.
silly stackoverflow validation.
silly stackoverflow validation.
silly stackoverflow validation.
silly stackoverflow validation.
silly stackoverflow validation.
silly stackoverflow validation.
silly stackoverflow validation.

Comment: "this is a good question because it's the only google result if you search the error"

Question quality =/= SEO metrics

Comment: so you would rather the next dev search this error and find nothing to go on. That makes no sense.

Comment: You can only find this exact error message here because it's including names from your code.

Comment: use this query: "Could not deduce (IHP.RouterSupport.AutoRoute". If I can't get these basic questions answered, I'm about to quit haskell. If you value haskell adoption, you should keep this question up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your View File: `View/HardwareVendors/Show.hs`

Change `value={get #id HardwareVendor}`
To: `value={inputValue (get #id HardwareVendor)}`
Notice the `inputValue` function call, it gives us the raw UUID value.

What happens when using `get #id HardwareVendor` in a View file, is the router will try to find the correct path to `HardwareVendor id`, but in this case there is no route setup for it. That's where the (`IHP.RouterSupport.AutoRoute`) error arises.

With `inputValue` we force it to give us a raw value, the UUID, instead of trying to create a routing path.

Related IHP Github Issue: https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/1013

Comment: thank you! Amazing to find out that this is an open, known issue for 2 years! How many other beginners encountered this issue and quit IHP? This issue will help future beginners avoid the roadblock I encountered.

Comment: And now it seems to have been fixed in the newest IHP https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/pull/1858  Thanks for bringing attention to it :-D